# SQL JOIN giving doubled values

Tags: sql, sql-server

EDIT ---

SQL FIDDLE sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f08bd/4
I couldn't load all the data into this as running out of limit on SQL FIDDLE but somehow the results are correct there with the little of sample data, but on my database it doubles somehow.

I am trying to display a total quantity of products, their weight and price. 
The results come from 4 different tables.

When I do this without join then I get proper values but when I use Join then I get double values on all outputs.

Without join I can't achieve this as these results need to be all in one table.

I tried not using Join and just including those tables in 'FROM' but that thrown me errors about issues converting to numeric. I also tried Union but didn't work.

When using no join and not trying to display all the values, I get the desired output but with missing columns that I missed out on purpose to test this.

```
SELECT PriceListTest.Description, COUNT(ItemCode) AS Quantity,
   SUM(Weight) AS 'Weight', Item.Pieces, PriceListTest.Price, 
   CAST(SUM( PriceListTest.Price * Weight) as 
  DECIMAL(10,2)) as 'Unit Price', CAST(SUM(PriceListTest.Price * Weight) as 
  DECIMAL(10,2))
  AS 'Nett Amount'
  FROM StockItems 
  INNER JOIN PriceListTest ON
  StockItems.ItemCode = PriceListTest.Description
  INNER JOIN Item ON StockItems.ItemCode = Item.ShortCode 
  WHERE Barcode IN (SELECT DISTINCT Barcode FROM StockOuttbl 
  WHERE ContainedID = 'isr5063' AND Status ='' GROUP BY Barcode) AND 
  PriceListTest.CustomerID = (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID From Customerstbl 
  WHERE CustomerID ='1')
  GROUP BY PriceListTest.Description, Item.Pieces, PriceListTest.Price;
```

Status in this case is empty, so that's not the issue

I getting these values:

```
Description Quantity    Weight  Pieces  Price   Unit Price  Nett Amount
MAJ        52         20242 0       1.23        24897.66    24897.66 

FLOCK       50        17206 0       1.23        21163.38    21163.38
```

This is the output I am looking:

```
Description Quantity    Weight  Pieces  Price   Unit Price  Nett Amount
MAJ       26            10121   0   1.23    12448.83‬   12448.83 

                                                             ‬
FLOCK       25          8603    0   1.23    10581.69    10581.69
```

When I don't use the PriceListTest in Join then I don't get the doubles, but then it's not exactly what I am looking for.

I get:

```
Description Quantity    Weight  Pieces
MAJ        26       10121   0        

FLOCK       25       8603   0
```

EDIT-- Added the data for the tables

```
PriceListTest---
OID ShortCode   Description CustomerID  Price
7372    MAJ       MAJ          1        1.23
7373    FLOCK     FLOCK        1        1.23

StockItems---
TimeStamp   DateStamp   ItemCode    Barcode         ID      Weight
104414357   20190701      MAJ   20190701104413935   7198    302
125350401   20190701      MAJ   20190701125349979   7220    360
125507063   20190703      MAJ   20190703125506641   7513    336

StockOutTbl---
ID  AddedTimeStamp  Quant   Line    UserID  Weight  Barcode       Status    Type    StockoutTimeStamp   StockoutUser    TerminalStockOut    TerminalAdded   AddedDateStamp  StockOutDateStamp   ContainedID
41  115020205         NULL  NULL    NULL        336 20190703125506641          NULL       115020208         user 1      TC20                NULL         20190704             20190704           isr5063



Item Table ----
OID ShortCode   ScreenCode  Description AdminOid    Kilos   Pieces  Inactive    CategoryTitleStr    BigBale
203       MAJ          MAJ        MAJ       NULL      0     0     0    45   1
204     FLOCK          FLOCK    FLOCK       NULL      0     0     0    45   1
```

Excuse me for the bad formatting.

I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you need `COUNT (DISTINCT ItemCode)`

Comment: I tried this and then the quantity just appears as 1 as I am trying to get the number of occurrences of that specific item code.

Comment: Hey man, why can't you create sql fiddle and post a link in question itself, it will help other users to create and modify query for you. You can create fiddle from here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f08bd/4 It seems to not double on here....Starting to think maybe I have doubled data in the actual Stock items and that could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

use subquery and distinct prcelist from 2nd table in subquery then use join 
and there is no need `GROUP BY Barcode` insside your subquery cause you alredy used distinct

```
SELECT PriceListTest.Description, COUNT(ItemCode) AS Quantity,
   SUM(Weight) AS 'Weight', Item.Pieces, PriceListTest.Price, 
   CAST(SUM( PriceListTest.Price * Weight) as 
  DECIMAL(10,2)) as 'Unit Price', CAST(SUM(PriceListTest.Price * Weight) as 
  DECIMAL(10,2))
  AS 'Nett Amount'
  FROM StockItems 
  INNER JOIN( select distinct * from  PriceListTest) as PriceListTest ON
  StockItems.ItemCode = PriceListTest.Description
  INNER JOIN Item ON StockItems.ItemCode = Item.ShortCode 
  WHERE Barcode IN (SELECT DISTINCT Barcode FROM StockOuttbl 
  WHERE ContainedID = 'isr5063' AND Status ='' ) AND 
  PriceListTest.CustomerID = (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID From Customerstbl 
  WHERE CustomerID ='1')
  GROUP BY PriceListTest.Description, Item.Pieces, PriceListTest.Price;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately my output is still exactly the same.

Comment: @Marcin share your pricelist table data in your question

Comment: I have edited the post and added the tables so you can have a look at them. Only included the required data. In terms of StockItems, there are 96 occurances of MAJ but there are 26 booked out of stock which appear in the StockOuttbl this should show me 26 but it shows 52. I have managed to get the 26 but that's only useful to display the quantity but doesn't work the same when I add all the other aspects to that. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Marcin so in stockitems table there are multiple MAZ which one you need

Comment: So basically what I am trying to achieve in this query is this: I want to get the product description, get the count of how much that item appears, get the sum of the weight for those items, calculate their price based on weight and then do the nett. In order to get this I need to know the barcode from stockouttbl, this barcode has a containedID as well So if a barcode is found with that containedID, then also the prices are based on customers, in this case I want to apply the prices for customerID = 1. I want to display all this information without the results doubling.